# Selenium unable to find the correct Xpath

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

When I record with Chrome I got this :

```json
{
    "title": "test",
    "steps": [
        {
            "type": "setViewport",
            "width": 1295,
            "height": 1294,
            "deviceScaleFactor": 1,
            "isMobile": false,
            "hasTouch": false,
            "isLandscape": false
        },
        {
            "type": "navigate",
            "url": "https://www.se.com/ww/en/search/rxm2ab2bd",
            "assertedEvents": [
                {
                    "type": "navigation",
                    "url": "https://www.se.com/ww/en/search/rxm2ab2bd",
                    "title": "Search - Schneider Electric"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "click",
            "target": "main",
            "selectors": [
                [
                    "#global-search-tab",
                    "div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > uiaas-search-result-product-v2:nth-child(2)",
                    "host > div > a > div > div > section.result-card__text-content-section > section"
                ],
                [
                    "xpath///*[@id=\"global-search-tab\"]",
                    "xpath//div/div/div/div[2]/div/uiaas-search-result-product-v2[1]",
                    "xpath//host/div/a/div/div/section[1]/section"
                ]
            ],
            "offsetY": 8,
            "offsetX": 158.625,
            "button": "secondary"
        },
       
    ]
}
```

Which when I replay, works well.
I then try to convert it to Selenium (python), this way :

```py
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id=\"global-search-tab\"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/uiaas-search-result-product-v2[1]/host/div/a/div/div/section[1]/section/div/div[2]/span/span"')
```

but it's not able to find anything.
I tried all kind of xpath, but nothing seems to work.
I'm getting desperate.

Comment: `[@id=\"global-search-tab\"]` I don't think you need the backslashes.

Comment: Where did the `div/div[2]/span/span` at the end of that xpath come from?  I don't see it in the recording.

Comment: The main question is how to translate recording done by Chrome to executable xpath ?